# Angular (Ionic) upload file to Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for a code sample of uploading a file from Angular 7 (Ionic 4) to a GCP storage bucket.

Here's the doc page, but there's no JavaScript or TypeScript sample: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload

To authenticate, I'd ideally like to use a GCP service account, but opening the bucket for write access would also work in the short term.

Note: The Node package @google-cloud/storage does not work in Angular and AngularFire seems to only support Firebase buckets (not vanilla GCP buckets).

Comment: this may give you some idea i think https://medium.com/francesco-pongetti/image-uploading-serving-with-google-cloud-storage-angularjs-d1e91721089a  &  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906257/uploading-image-to-bucket

Comment: thanks but the module referenced in that answer has been discontinued

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I never found anything other than Firebase storage which is more expensive

Comment: Thanks I'll upload files from the backend, its a bit tricky but I don't want to pay for a such functionnality